# How to set duration to scroll in scrollIntoView with smooth behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll

In my react project I have the following function in which I scroll into a element

```
const scroll = () => {
    const element = document.getElementById('element') as HTMLDivElement;
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
}
```

I would like to make the secoll slower, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should run correctly, but make sure the element exists. You can try any options from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView.

Or try to add this css:

```
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
    :root {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
}
```